# Parallel random numbers - generating SAME result for different numbers of tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, mpi, openmp

I have a number of SIMD style parallel applications that require large arrays of random numbers. The arrays are "distributed arrays", shared across multiple tasks and nodes with overlap to support spatial operators. What I need is a random number generator that will give the same result on multiple threads as it does on one thread. I could use a simplistic version where all tasks query a master task, but we would lose scalability.

So to summarize, I would like a scalable parallel random number generator that gives an equivalent result to using a master task to supply all the numbers.

Thanks in advance for any advice !

Chuck

P.S. Here is a simple serialized version that I would like to replace with a scalable implementation:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ParallelRandom {
  int size; // Number of tasks in the parallel context
  int rank; // Rank of this task in the parallel context
  Random r; // Random number generator used by master task

  public ParallelRandom( int numTasks, int taskRank, long seed ) {
    // Store size and rank
    size = numTasks;
    rank = taskRank;
    // initialize Random
    r = new Random(seed);
  }

  // Public method that must be called synchronously by all tasks
  public void nextRandomVector( double[] vector ) {
    int len = vector.length;
    // Loop over all tasks in the context
    for (int itask=0; itask<size; itask++) {
      // Set the return values for this task, otherwise just advance the random number
      if (rank == itask)
         for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
            vector[i] = r.nextGaussian();
      else
         for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
            r.nextGaussian();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seed must be same for all and you can use custom generator derived from modulo operator and it is pseudo-random. Something like Lehmer Generator, with some known coprime parameters.

Comment: Assuming that the first two numbers returned by the random number generator are `N1` and then `N2`, and that `P1` and then `P2` requests a random number so that `P1` receives `N1`, do you want `P2` to receive `N1` or do you want it to receive `N2`?  In other words, do you want the RNGs to behave like there's a single RNG queried by each processor (meaning that `P2` gets `N2`), or do you want them to behave like each processor gets its own RNG (meaning that `P2` gets `N1`)?

Comment: See the updated example code in the original post for clarification.

Comment: Just being curious, why do you need exactly the same pseudo-random number sequence? A true stochastic simulation would not depend on the actual numbers as one would usually average over cases or would be interested in global (again - averaged) quantities.

Comment: The technical area is geostatistics, where we are attempting to numerically simulate geologic variability. We create "realizations" and then work with them for a bit, so being able to re-create the same sequence is useful, but not necessary as you point out.